# Moving subtags up in html with beautiful soup in python 3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to edit a large number of html files with a beautifulsoup script. Some of my html files contain blocks like the following where img tags are nested withing a tags.

```
<p>
    <a class="" data-api-endpoint="https://hcpss.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/124/grade-1-routines" data-api-returntype="Page" href="grade-1-routines.html" id="" target="" title="">
        <img alt="1-icon-file-download.png" data-api-endpoint="https://hcpss.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/124/files/3523713" data-api-returntype="File" src="1-icon-file-download.png"/>
   </a>
   <a class="instructure_file_link instructure_scribd_file" data-api-endpoint="https://hcpss.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/124/files/3523689" data-api-returntype="File" href="closure_at_a_glance.docx" id="" target="" title="closure_at_a_glance.docx">
Closure at a Glance
   </a>
</p>
```

This chain of tags causes an issue with the program I am importing the html files into. To fix this, I would like to remove the surrounding a tag altogether, so that the result would look like this.

```
<p>
   <img alt="1-icon-file-download.png" data-api-endpoint="https://hcpss.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/124/files/3523713" data-api-returntype="File" src="1-icon-file-download.png"/>
   <a class="instructure_file_link instructure_scribd_file" data-api-endpoint="https://hcpss.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/124/files/3523689" data-api-returntype="File" href="closure_at_a_glance.docx" id="" target="" title="closure_at_a_glance.docx">
Closure at a Glance
   </a>
</p>
```

I attempted a script that would do this here.

```
for img in soup.find_all('img'):
if img.parent.name == 'a':
    img.parent.decompose()
    print(img)
```

Running the script produces...

```
<None></None>
```

In the console and results in the  and  tag both being deleted. What can I do to modify this script so that only the parent is deleted, and the child takes it's place?

Comment: check function `replace_with`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`replace_with()`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with):

```
for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    parent = img.parent
    if parent.name == 'a':
        parent.replace_with(img)

print(soup)
```

**Output**:

```
<p>
<img alt="1-icon-file-download.png" data-api-endpoint="https://hcpss.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/124/files/3523713" data-api-returntype="File" src="1-icon-file-download.png"/>
<a class="instructure_file_link instructure_scribd_file" data-api-endpoint="https://hcpss.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/124/files/3523689" data-api-returntype="File" href="closure_at_a_glance.docx" id="" target="" title="closure_at_a_glance.docx">
Closure at a Glance
   </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for elaborating on bobrobbob's comment, this works precisely as I needed it to!